# sum of the reciprocals of the ZetaPrimes

Tags: calculus

I am interesting in the zeros of following series
$$\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{z^j}{P(j+1)}$$ I try to use the wolfram Mathematica for z=-1
$$\text{NSum}\left[\frac{(-1)^j}{P(j+1)},\{j,0,\infty \},\text{Method}\to \text{WynnEpsilon}\right]$$ and get the value -0.532032 but I do not sure ,it seems wrong using double condensation transformation and Wynn algorimth I get the following result
[image]
Could you check the results by other methods?
note that P(1) is Infinity but it doesn't affect the result.

Comment: Does $P(z)$ stand for prime zeta function?

Comment: P(z) is the  prime zeta function

Comment: Note that $P(1)$ tends to infinity so you can start the sum from $2$ as your prime zeta function is in the denominator

Comment: @Charlessilva Tell that in the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meant $P(s)=\sum_{p \ prime} p^{-s}$. I don't see why anyone would expect to know (and care) of the zeros of $\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{z^{k+1}}{P(k+2)}$.

Note that we can find its poles and meromorphic continuation to the whole of $\Bbb{C}$.

$$2^{-2}-(P(2)-2^{-2}) > 2^{-2}-(\log \zeta(2)-2^{-2})> 0$$ so the generalized Dirichlet series $$F(s)=1/P(s)=
2^s \sum_{k\ge 0} (-2^s \sum_{p \ge 3} p^{-s})^k = \sum_{n,m} a_{n,m} n^{-s} 2^{s(m+1)}$$
converges absolutely on $\Re(s)\ge 2$.

Note that $a_{n,m}=0$ if $n/2^{m+1} \le 1/2$ and that $\{ n/2^{m+1}, a_{n,m}\ne 0\}$ is a discrete set.

Your function is
$$x\sum_{n,m} \frac{a_{n,m} 2^{2(m+1)}/n^2}{1-x 2^{m+1}/n}= \sum_{k\ge 0} x^{k+1} F(k+2)$$
The LHS gives its meromorphic continuation to $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: could you , explain generalized Dirichlet series $$F(s)=1/P(s)=
2^s \sum_{k\ge 0} (-2^s \sum_{p \ge 3} p^{-s})^k = \sum_{n,m} a_{n,m} n^{-s} 2^{s(m+1)}$$ ?? . where does it come from and is it correct

Comment: Expand in geometric series $\frac1{1+ (2^sP(s)-1)}$

Comment: thanks @reuns nice idea